# action bar not showing with support library

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to implement an activity with an action bar with the v7 support library. But the action bar just does not show. The menu items are showing as a normal menu list when i touch the menu button. What am i doing wrong?

Manifest.xml :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".ChatSession_ActionBarActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

chatsession_menu.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/dummy1"
            android:title="dummy1 menu option"
            android:showAsAction="always"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search">

        </item>
    </menu>
```

ChatSession_ActionBarActivity :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class ChatSession_ActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actionbaractivity_chatsession);
        getSupportActionBar().show(); //this line is not required, but just giving it a try

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chatsession_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the action bar does not show up?. post the snap shot. You applied a action bar theme to the activity and if you reference appcompat you should see the actionbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dummy1"
        android:title="dummy1 menu option"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search">

    </item>
</menu>
```

From the docs

> Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace
>   defined in the  tag. This is necessary when using any XML
>   attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do
>   not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use
>   your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the
>   support library.

Comment: @faizal ok But you say actionbar does not show up. Your description seems wrong. Coz i don't see a problem with actionbar itself

Comment: By actionbar, i am referring to the menu icon that appears at the top right corner. It appeared only after i tried your solution. I am not sure if my referring to it as the actionbar is correct. Maybe i should refer to it as acionbar menu icon?

Comment: @faizal right the action bar shows up not the menu item. With the above you should get the item in the right place

Comment: ok. But if i am implement a normal activity(not Action bar activity), it looks exactly like an action bar activity without the icons. So that makes me wonder if there is any way of finding out if an action bar actually shows up.

Comment: @faizal it will appear in the actionbar as long as there is enough space. If there are more items and no space the items appear in the overflow menu. Read the docs. ActionBarActivity with appcomapt is for api level below 11.

Comment: @faizal above api level 11 you have native actionbar and there is no need for actionbaractivity or appcompat